# Duplicate workbook and execute macro in that file

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a VBA code that copies the workbook in a separate workbook (workbook2) and converts in that second workbook all the formulas to values, the coversion should not be done in workbook 1 (the active one). I found a code that does the conversion but I don't know how to make it execute it in workbook 2. Then I should save this workbook 2. Any Ideas? Below the code

```
Sub ConvertFormulasToValuesAllWorksheets()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range



    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each rng In ws.UsedRange

        If rng.HasFormula Then

            rng.Formula = rng.Value

        End If

    Next rng

    Next ws

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\myusid\Desktop\myfolder\workbook2.xlsx" _
     , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False ' need to 
     change the name of the folder
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True


      On Error GoTo 0
      End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. Also remove the `For Each rng` loop - just call `.Value = .Value` on the `ws.UsedRange`. Then `SaveAs` with a new name.

Comment: In need the On Error Resume Next because it is showing an error that does not affect the overall result. Otherwise it shows a problem related to an array that cannot be copied

Comment: No - handle the error please. A blanket `On Error Resume Next` at the beginning is bad practice.

Comment: Please read [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling) for how to do a proper error handling. `On Error Resume Next` is no proper error handling.

Comment: Thank a lot, I will try to solve it first

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that gives you some flexibility setting the file name and path in variables.

Also some good practices:

1. Set your variables to something understandable
2. Declare all your variables
3. At the top of your modules put `Option Explicit` so variable declaration is required
4. Indent your code

---

**EDIT:** Added keep same sheets' order as source book and delete extra sheets

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConvertFormulasToValuesAllWorksheets()

    Dim newBook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileFullPath As String


    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Build the path
    filePath = "C:\Temp\"  ' "C:\Users\myusid\Desktop\myfolder\"

    fileName = "workbook2.xlsx"

    fileFullPath = filePath & fileName

    ' Add a new workbook
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

    ' Save it with the path built
    newBook.SaveAs fileName:=fileFullPath ', FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    For Each sourceSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ' Copy the sheet
        sourceSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(sourceSheet.Index)

        Set targetSheet = newBook.Worksheets(sourceSheet.Name)

        ' Copy/paste values
        targetSheet.UsedRange.Value = sourceSheet.UsedRange.Value
    Next sourceSheet

    ' Delete other sheets
    For Each targetSheet In newBook.Worksheets
        If Not WorksheetExists(targetSheet.Name, ThisWorkbook) Then
            targetSheet.Delete
        End If
    Next targetSheet


CleanExit:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    GoTo CleanExit

End Sub

Private Function WorksheetExists(sheetName As String, targetBook As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim evalSheet As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set evalSheet = targetBook.Sheets(sheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    WorksheetExists = Not (evalSheet Is Nothing)

End Function
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: If I can suggest: `targetSheet.UsedRange.Value = targetSheet.usedRange.Value`- and you no longer need the clipboard.

Comment: You copied over the sheet - I think that takes care of the format.

Comment: Absolutely! Thnx @bigben

Comment: Thanks, this is working well, just one thing: Is it possible to have in the new file the same worksheet order ? With this code the order gets reversed, and also "Sheet1", "Sheet2" and "Sheet3" in the workbook2 can be deleted

Comment: Code adjusted with @BigBen suggestion and added keeping same order and deleting extra sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub ConvertFormulasToValuesAllWorksheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

' the workbook to copy
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

' Copy all sheets from wb1 to new workbook
wb1.Sheets.Copy
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook


With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End with

For Each ws In wb2.Sheets
   With ws
       .Cells.Copy
       .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
   End With
Next ws

wb2.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\myusid\Desktop\myfolder\workbook2.xlsx" _
     ,FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```